# Building an android native application from android source code

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

I am having difficulty with building my native android application using NDK. There are no binders, certain headers missing, etc.

But I have earlier experience with building using Android source 2.3, where I used to built android first and then doing `mmm /path/to/my/application/ -B` would build my application, but that was a forked android version.

This time I want to do it for Android 4.4, but before downloading it, I want to know whether default android sources come with commands like `mmm` and `lunch` and whether I can build my native application using it.

Comment: If you want your app to run on unmodified Android 4.4 devices, and probably 5.0, etc., you should only use headers and libraries that are part of official NDK distribution. Often it is possible to copy small parts of AOSP to your app when you need some functionality that is beyond NDK.